# Learning order: improper integrals or integrals applications first?

Tags: calculus, self-learning, education

I am first year's non-math student and during our calculus lectures we were first introduced to definite integrals and their applications, and then to improper integrals. After that we went straight for differential equations.

I am now preparing for an exam and I am wondering what should I learn first:

- **integrals applications** (area between curves, arc length; parametric functions)

or

- **improper integrals**

Here's our pdfs with exercises:

- https://www.docdroid.net/RrF6Q0r/int-appl.pdf (applications)
- https://www.docdroid.net/Ssvemuw/improp-int.pdf (improper integrals)

Would anyone be able to glance at those exercises from integral applications and give it a guess if I need to know improper integrals in order to solve some of them?

Basically, I am wondering if should I reverse the order introduced to us by the teacher and learn improper integrals first.

I just want to take the most optimal approach.

Kind of weird question, thank you for giving me an idea.

Comment: You definitely need improper integrals for these questions.

Comment: Would you be able to point out just one specific exercise in which I would need the improper integrals? Also, I cannot accept your answer because it's a comment.